# How to log response body in gin while I redirect the initial request

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm trying to log the response body of a request that has been redirected.

```js
func main() {
 r := gin.Default()

 eanAPI := api.NewEanAPI()

  v1 := r.Group("/v1")
 v1.POST("/*action", eanAPI.Redirect, middleware.SaveRequest())
  
  
 port := os.Getenv("PORT")
 if len(port) == 0 {
  port = "8000"
 }
 r.Run(":" + port)
}

func (api *eanAPI) Redirect(ctx *gin.Context) {
 forwardToHost := "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"
 url := ctx.Request.URL.String()
 ctx.Redirect(http.StatusTemporaryRedirect, forwardToHost)
}

type bodyLogWriter struct {
 gin.ResponseWriter
 body *bytes.Buffer
}

func (w bodyLogWriter) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
 w.body.Write(b)
 return w.ResponseWriter.Write(b)
}

func SaveRequest() gin.HandlerFunc {
 return func(c *gin.Context) {
  c.Next()
  blw := &bodyLogWriter{body: bytes.NewBufferString(""), ResponseWriter: c.Writer}
  c.Writer = blw
  c.Next()
  statusCode := c.Writer.Status()
  fmt.Println("status: ", statusCode)
  if statusCode <= 400 {
   //ok this is an request with error, let's make a record for it
   // now print body (or log in your preferred way)
   fmt.Println("Response body: " + blw.body.String())
  }
 }
```

Unfortunately, the body response is always empty. Maybe the redirection or the middleware is messing with my body response

When I tried with postman I can see the body response coming! You can try it by a POST on https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts. It should return a payload with an id in the body response

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response body you're seeing in the browser/postman is from the page you're being redirected *to*. The page doing the actual redirecting likely has no response body, just a status and a `Location` header. This is the expected behavior of a redirect. If you want to try to capture the body of the page you're redirecting to, you can't actually use redirects for that (the redirect handler isn't involved in the final request); you'd have to fully proxy the request rather than redirecting it. Proxying is very different from redirecting though, so make sure that's really the behavior you're after.